# Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, testnets, goerli

The test works fine on the local hardhat network, but when I run this test on staging i.e Goerli I get the following error in the picture.

The error seems to occur at the txResponse.wait() line as you can see all the console logs work fine before that.

[image: Error]

Here's how the full error :

> Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0x816eb8c5abf3f9968f5bc9924919e9c37685bca41cf37038968c0a84fd413e8b", transaction={"hash":"0x816eb8c5abf3f9968f5bc9924919e9c37685bca41cf37038968c0a84fd413e8b","type":0,"accessList":null,"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0x586d5835978fB8B8352DdA4D8E8Cd1668D32b440","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x989680"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x01bae258"},"to":"0xcA0D8824e43B3235486cec5C228E2E4B8CB0ddd0","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"nonce":29,"data":"0x991466690000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e516d5757515375504d5336615843625a4b70456a504850555a4e324e6a42335972684a5448735634583376623274000000000000000000000000000000000000","r":"0x40c922bb31a7e0e283958eb74f6f3443f3f6530fa0adffa47e35cdc9f2626eb3","s":"0x15644646ca04c8ab558ba2454a6473a37b7e137d0e23eac87f7d6377fbe0a650","v":46,"creates":null,"chainId":5}, receipt={"to":"0xcA0D8824e43B3235486cec5CNumber":7672792,"confirmations":2,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0e6664"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x989680"},"status":0,"type":0,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.1)      at Logger.makeError (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)      at Logger.throwError (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)      at EthersProviderWrapper. (node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\base-provider.ts:1549:24)      at step (node_modules@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:48:23)      at Object.next (node_modules@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:29:53)      at fulfilled (node_modules@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:20:58)

Answer (score 0):

Check which chainId you are using. I mean which you set goerli eth or polygon matic in Metamask Wallet. If you set polygon and currently you are using eth goerli in Metamask, then you get this error